# Network security group - How to collect some IPs to one group

Tags: azure

How can i grant access (Create a firewall rule) in "Network security group" on azure, to a group of "Source IPs"?

i would like to do that in order to be able to add other IPs in the future in one place to a group (Such: Office, Managers, etc.) instead of adding the IPs manually to each rule i may have.

its only available for one IP or range.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is no way of doing that, either IP or CIDR notation range.</strike>
Actually, you can separate them using comma. Like so: `10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6` or so: `10.0.0.0/26,10.1.0.0/24`

Never knew.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
On that way, if i want to add or remove IP, i will need to do it for every relevant rule. i am looking for a way to use IP Groups like "Office IPs" so i will be able to manage the relevant IPs on one place.

Comment: that one doesnt exist for sure